# What is this marine type water proof connector?

Tags: connector, identification, waterproof

Does anyone know what this connector is by any chance?

[image: Female Side]
[image: Male Side]

Comment: What is the instrument?

Answer (score 1):

A closeup of the face of the cable, and dimensions of the port, would help. As would some info on the device it is plugging into.

But I would guess it’s some sort of Amphenol connector. Maybe something  similar to this: [C01630G00680012](https://www.amphenol-sine.com/C01630G00680012-6-PE-Female-receptacle-solder-with-turned-contacts-black_p_5725.html).

There are hundreds of such interconnects, so to get good results you’ll need to provide good information.

Comment: It is also possibly custom mold over a standard pinout connector. There are hundreds of small companies that have these quasi-custom or application specific variants of interconnects that otherwise appear standard

Comment: @crasic Agreed.